# What is the $\mathbb{P} [S_n=0 \mbox{ for infinitely many $n$}]$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

For random variables $X_i$ and define the sum $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

$$\limsup_{n} \mathbb{P} [S_n=0]?$$

Comment: No. We always call the probability "infinitely often" denoted by "i.o." and the right hand limsup is the limsup of sets but not probability. You can check Borel-Cantelli's lemma to know more.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea infinitely often does not mean infinitely many?

Comment: Yes, I mean we use the notation more often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you cannot express $P[S_n=0 \, \text {for infinitely many n} \, ] $ in terms of the numbers $P[S_n=0]$. What you can say is $P[S_n=0 \, \text {for infinitely many n} \, ]  \geq \lim \sup P[S_n=0]$. This is a consequence of Fatou's Lemma.

Comment: Is it not same as  $\lim sup A_n = \{ω : ω ∈ A_n i.o.\}$?

Comment: @BobO. Yes, tat is definition of $\lim \sup A_n$. But you cannot evaluate the proabability of this as $\lim \sup P(A_n)$.

Comment: Can we consider the expectation $E(\mathbf{1}_{\{S_n=0\}})$ to get $P( S_n i.o.)$?

Comment: @BobO. There is no useful formula for $P(S_n=0 \, i.o. )$

Comment: I mean if we know $E(\mathbf{1}_{\{S_n=0\}})\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. How about $P(S_n=0 \mbox{ for infinitely many} n)=0 $ or $>0$?

Comment: There are examples where $P(S_n =0 \, i.o. )=1$ even though $P(S_n=0) \to 0$! Symmetric random walk on the integers gives such an example. @BobO.